# Backbone.js: smart update of a list of changed attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model, save, crud

I know this problem have been discussed several times, but I could not find an answer to one of its many aspects, that I'll try to explain here.

Model `save()` keeps sync between client and server. Backbone.js pushes you to use it in one of these 2 ways (afaik):

1. Save all the items of a model: this will send everything to the
   server, even attributes used only on the client side and attributes
   that have not been changed. This is the default for new models (when
   `model.isNew()` returns `true`).
2. Save with `patch:true` will only send changed attributes of the
   model to the server. In Backbone, it means that **ONLY** the
   attributes returned by `changedAttributes()` will be sent.

The point is that `changedAttributes()` ONLY returns the changes since the LAST `change` event. This is useful for models that are not updating all the time, and actually can afford to automatically make an ajax request on any change.

But if you have a model that is constantly changing (for example a code/text editor or an element that can be dragged/dropped and its position should be tracked), you cannot just save at every single `change` event. You need to save at time intervals, ALL the changed attributes since the last time you called `save()`.

Do you think Backbone.js actually provides a good support for this kind of synchronization? Does Bakcbone.js track changes **since last** `save()` (and not only since last `change` event)? Or you have to do it "manyally"?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to extend backbone models with your own base model.

```
var BaseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    save: function(key, val, options){
        var attrs
        if (key == null || typeof key === 'object') {
          attrs = key;
          options = val;
        } else {
           (attrs = {})[key] = val;
        }  
        attrs = _.extend(this.unsaved || {}, attrs);
        this.unsaved = {};
        return Backbone.Model.prototype.save.call(this, attrs, options);
    },
    set: function(key, val, options) {
       var attr
       if (key == null) return this;
       if (typeof key === 'object') {
          attrs = key;
          options = val;
       } else {
         (attrs = {})[key] = val;
       }
       this.unsaved = _.extend(this.unsaved || {}, attrs);
       return Backbone.Model.prototype.save.call(this, attrs, options);
    }
});
```

Totally untested code, but should be very close to what you need to do.